# Cucumber BDD different features requiring similar step

Tags: java, spring, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

In my application I have two feature files:

```
processing.feature
copy.feature
```

For these I have two step definition files:

Processing Feature:

```
public class ProcessingFeature {

    @Qualifier("moverA")
    @Autowired
    private IFileMover mover;


    @Given("check file is available")
    public void load() {

    }

    @When("the file is there at the location")
    public void moveFile() {
        output= mover.move(info);

    }   
}
```

Copy Feature:

```
public class CopyFeature {

    @Qualifier("moverB")
    @Autowired
    private IFileMover mover;


    @Given("check file is available")
    public void load() {

    }

    @When("the file is there at the location")
    public void moveFile() {
        output= mover.move(info);

    }   
}
```

In both my feature files, I run `check file is available` as `@Given` step. My first question is, they are identical step definitions sitting in both step def file. What is the correct pattern so this code is not duplicated and both features can make use of it?

Secondly, both features run `the file is there at the location` but one uses `MoverA` & the Other uses `MoverB`. But the idea remains same. Again I don't like the duplication so how best can I re-use maybe through some abstraction ?

Ofcourse I get `cucumber.runtime.DuplicateStepDefinitionException: Duplicate step definitions` exception but I am curious to see what is correct pattern to solve these kind of problems

Answer (score 0):

Steps can only be defined once. Step definitions are global, and not specific to a scenario or feature. Since a step can only have one definition, code duplication is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the following page from Cucumber : https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/step-organization/
It will help you organize correctly your glue code.
As Greg said, the step definitions are global, it is an anti-pattern to create feature-specific steps :
https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/anti-patterns/#feature-coupled-step-definitions

In your feature file, I think there is a confusion between When steps (action : ie copying the file or processing the file) and Then steps (expected result : the file should be at which location).
Your step definitions should be more like :

```
@When("I copy the following file:(.*)")
public void copyFile(String fileName) {
    xxxx calling system under test xxxx
}   

@When("I process the following file:(.*)")
public void processFile(String fileName) {
    xxxx calling system under test xxxx
}   

@Then("the file is at the following location:(.*)")
public void checkFileExistence(String fileLocation) {
    Assert.assertTrue(xxxxx);
}
```

To share state between steps, you can use the World object pattern :
cf https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/state/

Answer (score 0):

This is downside when using plain text file and step mapping for BDD implementation. Alternate to this and similar issues because of additional feature file layer is, using [pure java implementation of scenario](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/runtime_scenario.html). It will eliminate extra layer of feature files and certainly step definition files and allows you to follow behavior driven development.